# Allegro5 functions are not recognized for code completion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, allegro5

Most of the functions in the allegro5 header files are defined as macros that follow the pattern `bold_is_the_type_of_the_data`:

```
AL_FUNC(return_type, function_name, (function_parameters));
```

Is there any way I can force IntelliSense to add those functions to the code completion?

I am using Visual Studio Code Version 1.16.0 and have tested this with Tag Parser and Default engines.